# Change one theme/accent color to another accent color for all shapes in a PPT file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created this code to replace one accent colors of the template with another (ObjectThemeColors), the Brightness (tint and shade) element is over-ruled and all shades of the old accent colors are replaced with the same shade as that of the given new color, can anybody help to preserve the brightness/shades while changing to new accent colors?

[image: Form Screenshot]

```
Sub ReplaceColorNew(OldColor As String, NewColor As String)

Dim oeff As Effect
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim oPP As Placeholders

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
    'groups
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            For x = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count
                With oShp.GroupItems(x)
                    If .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                       .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                    End If

                    If .Line.Visible Then
                        If .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                           .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                        End If
                    End If

                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            For y = 1 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs.Count
                                If .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                                   .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Else
            With oShp 'other shapes
            ' Fill
                If .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                End If

                ' Line
                If Not .Type = msoTable Then
                    If .Line.Visible = msoTrue Then
                        If .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                            .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                ' Text
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                        For y = 1 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs.Count
                            If .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(OldColor) + 5 Then
                                .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = Conversion.CLng(NewColor) + 5
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
'oShp = Nothing
    Next oShp
Next oSld


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before changing the ObjectThemeColor, pick up the current TintAndShade and brightness, then apply them again after changing the ObjectThemeColor.  Simplified example:

```
With oSh.Fill.ForeColor

    lThemeColor = .ObjectThemeColor
    sBrightness = .Brightness
    sTintShade = .TintAndShade

    .ObjectThemeColor = lThemeColor + 1
    .Brightness = sBrightness
    .TintAndShade = sTintShade

End With
```

Actually, I think preserving Brightness alone *might* be sufficient; give it a try and let us know.

Comment: wow, thats a way simpler fix than what I expected!! Thanks Steve!
Yes, just Brightness is suffice.

Comment: Hi all, in this case, instead of picking up the brightness from the shape and applying from after changing ObjectThemeColor, how can we apply a new brightness while changing themecolors?  when I change the brightness value, brightness of all the shapes change

Comment: @Jegan I'm not following your question ... can you explain in more detail please?  Thanks!

Comment: the requirement changed so that question was not needed.
Could you please check this post, your input is invaluable, thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68180372/ppt-vba-change-a-shapes-accent-color-from-one-theme-color-to-another?noredirect=1#comment120508439_68180372