# PPT VBA: Change a shape's accent color from one theme color to another

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PPT VBA, I'm trying to change all shapes in a file that are in one accent color to another. I supply the values from this form to my function, but its not accepting the OldColor and NewColor (themecolors) as msoThemeColorAccent1 but only takes as 15 instead. but it is accepting when I give msoThemeColorAccent1 for Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor; just not accepting when supplied from the function arguments.  can anybody please suggest a solution?

this is my form:
[image: Form]

these are my code blocks:

```
Private Sub cmdApply_Click()
    ReplaceColors cboOldColor.Value, cboNewColor.Value, cboOldTint.Text, cboNewTint.Text
End Sub

Sub ReplaceColors(OldColor As Variant, NewColor As Variant, OldTint As String, NewTint As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim sBrightness
Dim oColor, nColor As ThemeColor
Dim oPP As Placeholders

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
        'groups
          If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            'not groups
            Else
            With oShp 'other shapes
                ' Fill
                If .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = OldColor And .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = OldTint Then
                        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = NewColor
                        .Fill.BackColor.Brightness = NewTint
                End If

                ' Line
                If Not .Type = msoTable Then
                    If .Line.Visible = msoTrue Then
                        If .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = OldColor And .Line.ForeColor.Brightness = OldTint Then
                            .Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = NewColor
                            .Line.ForeColor.Brightness = NewTint
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                ' Text
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                        For y = 1 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs.count
                            If .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = OldColor And .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.Brightness = OldTint Then
                                .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = NewColor
                                .TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(y).Font.Color.Brightness = NewTint
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            End If
    'oShp = Nothing
        Next oShp
    Next oSld
End Sub
```

Comment: If the OldColor and NewColor something you are passing from the userform, I think you may have to do some datatype conversion of the contents before passing. for example: x=clng(textbox1.value) . Not sure if this may solve it but something you can try, if u haven't already.

Comment: Brightness expects a Single, not a String. ObjectThemeColor expects a Long, not a Variant. If that doesn't help, try using _SchemeColor_ instead of ObjectThemeColor.

Comment: Thanks Charlie and John for the inputs.
I have tried converting to CLng / CSng, still getting type mismatch error. Also schemeColor enum supports less accent colors only, I need all 10 accent colors in the palette.

Comment: Also when I use the correct data types in the function arguments, like this
Sub ReplaceColors(OldColor As ThemeColor, NewColor As ThemeColor, OldTint As Single, NewTint As Single) - its giving Object Required error in the function call statement in the form